# Changing directory in shell_exec does not work

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

I have this routine for running BASH-scripts:

```
// $cmd is something like '/var/tmp/script.sh'
function runshell($cmd)
{
    $work_dir = dirname($cmd);
    $work_file = basename($cmd);
    $message = shell_exec("cd " . $work_dir . " && " . $work_file . " 2>&1");
    return $message;
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't change directory and `$work_file` is never found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution1**

Use full path to file

```
$message = shell_exec($work_dir . "/" . $work_file . " 2>&1");
```

**Solution2**

Also you can use `chdir()` for this. It will change current working directory of the php script.

```
chdir($work_dir);
$message = shell_exec($work_file . " 2>&1");
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. But why do I wanna change directory? Because inside script there are references to other files which are located in the same dir and when I use the full path as you suggested those referenced files aren't found

Comment: Thanks. I try `chdir` but still get this annoying `sh: 1: test.sh: not found`.

Comment: It is really annoying and frustrating: `$work_file` returns `'test.sh'` and `$work_dir` returns '/var/tmp'. `chdir()` returns `TRUE`

Comment: What if `shell_exec` uses some other ways of detecting working directory and is not influenced by `chdir`?

Comment: Thanks, Harikrishnan! It's been all my fault. Just applied `chmod u+x` and now `chdir` idea works magically.